# Error replace() Javascript Jquery

Tags: javascript, html5, jquery-validate

Estoy haciendo una funcion en `Jquery` y `Javascript` en el que tengo que pasar un parametro por la url.

Este parámetro contiene los caracteres `/` y `+`, por lo que lo tengo que reemplazarlos para que no haya problemas en la url.

Al utilizar el código:

```
var selectId = $("#parametroSel").val().replace(/\//g, ":::").replace(/+/g, "::::");
```

En la consola de javascript me registra este error:

```
SyntaxError: nothing to repeat
```

¿Cuál puede ser el problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya he encontrado el problema, estaba aqui:

```
replace(/+/g, "::::");
```

Tenía que escapar el `+`

```
replace(/\+/g, "::::");
```

Answer (score 3):

Se que la pregunta es sobre replace, pero te sugiero utilizar una [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) para encodear datos que debes enviar en un query string.

Lo fundamental es que realiza **la codificación standard** o URL encoding que sera fácil, incluso transparente de decodificar del lado del servidor.

```js
var uri = "http://ejemplo.com/prueba uno.html?symbols=\+:/&";

console.log(
  encodeURIComponent(uri)
);
```